# systemd, journal receiving raw log

Tags: systemd, syslog, journald

one common paradigm on all other syslog implementations (rsyslog, syslog-ng, readlog, etc) is to exchange log entries via UDP514 in plain text format.

How do I enable systemd-journal-remote to receive logs in such format?

(I know there are plugins to more complex log providers to emulate the new https format used by default by systemd-journal-remote, but i'm dealing with dumb appliances that can only send the old, original, plain text format)

Answer (score 0):

ended up using rsyslog with the `omjournal` output log. This way the logs go to journald and are "unified" in the syslog ecosystem. Have the advantage of working across containers too.

```
# /etc/rsyslog.conf
...
module(load="omjournal")
template(name="journal" type="list") {
  constant(value="remote" outname="MESSAGE")
  property(name="$!event-type" outname="EVENT_TYPE")
}
action(type="omjournal" template="journal")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to redirect remote log messages to systemd journal using a example configuration from  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1428247 :

```
module(load="omjournal") 
ruleset(name="remote") {
    action(type="omjournal")
}
input(type="imtcp" port="514" ruleset="remote")
```

It works on Ubuntu Server 18.04 with rsyslog, in my case using the tcp module.